# How correctly use AVG in query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In `PostgreSQL` database I have table called `answers` which looks like this:

```
| EMPLOYEE | QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT          | OPTION_ID | OPTION_TEXT  |
|----------|-------------|------------------------|-----------|--------------|
| Bob      | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1         | 1            |
| Alex     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 9         | 9            |
| Oliver   | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 6         | 6            |
| Bob      | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 3         | 3            |
| Alex     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 9         | 9            |
| Oliver   | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 8         | 8            |
| Bob      | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 2         | 2            |
| Alex     | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 9         | 9            | 
| Oliver   | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 8         | 8            |
```

In this table you can notice that I have 3 question and user answers to them. Users answer questions on a scale of one to ten. I'm trying to find the number of users whose avg of answers to questions 1, 2 and 3 is greater than 5 without deep subquery. For example only 2 user has `avg(option_text)` for three question more than 5. They are Alex and Oliver.

I tried to use this script, but it's work not as I expected:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN (AVG(OPTION_ID) FILTER(WHERE QUESTION_ID IN(61, 62))) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT
FROM
    ANSWERS;
```

**ERROR**:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select all employees that have an average response of greater than 5 for questions 1,2,3 with a group by query

```
select employee, avg(option_id)
from answers
where question_id in (1,2,3)
group by employee
having avg(option_id) > 5
and count(distinct question_id) = 3 
-- the last part is only needed if you only want employees that answered all questions
```

To count the number of users that have an average that's greater than 5

```
select count(*) from (
    select employee
    from answers
    where question_id in (1,2,3)
    group by employee
    having avg(option_id) > 5
    and count(distinct question_id) = 3
)
```

Comment: Hello! I started with the same query at start. Only difference I didn't use last count as you. In fact I need to know the number of users whose avg is more than 5. In this case I need to use subquery as I understand. It's not what I want. I want to find the way to make this task without subquery. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek the `having avg(option_id) > 5` part returns users whose avg is more than 5. What was wrong with the query that you started out with?

Comment: You code return list of users. I need to know the count. To find the count I used subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This following query should work-

```
SELECT
DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
FROM ANSWERS
WHERE QUESTION_ID NOT IN(61, 62)
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
HAVING AVG(OPTION_ID) > 5
```

Check demo [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d2a4fc56ab76883f1028fa1020ae1dcc)